# sitecore edit frame buttonRoot isn't set for edit frame

Tags: editor, sitecore, frame, edit

I'm trying to have the page editor functionality working on my sitecore 7. 
I created a user control and I'm getting this error "buttonRoot isn't set for edit frame"

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BodyText.ascx.cs" Inherits="Website.layouts.Sublayouts.Page_Sublayouts.BodyText" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="sc" Namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" Assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" %>
<sc:EditFrame ID="EditField" runat="server" Buttons="/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default">
    <sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" ID="fldMainContent" FieldName="Body Text" />
</sc:EditFrame>
```

Does anyone knows what I'm missing?

Cheers and thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have the EditFrame? You don't need that to make the content editable in the Page Editor. It is only if you need some special buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, this exception could occur due to different reasons. 
Please check following:

1. Make sure that "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default" item exists in the "core" database and you have read access to it.
2. If your Edit Frame/Frames has the "Buttons" property, please make sure that the item specified in that property exists in your Core database and your user have access to it.

(The item should be located under the "/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons" item).

Comment: Verified that. Apparently the problem was not related with the error shown. On the page init there was some validation that was kicking the user of the session. THanks Chris

Comment: Are you able to provide any information as to what you did to resolve this one?

Comment: Goose - you too, if you find a solution.  I'm getting this after a user has been idle for a long time.  I'm thinking a mismatch of cookie/session/etc timeouts might be the issue.

Comment: For me, this error occurred when I tried to open the Experience Editor while logged in with an external account (which had no permissions for content editing).